# Uncaught ReferenceError: getDetails is not defined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to execute the following `JavaScript` code, but I'm getting error.

```
var services = [{place_id:'okkkkkk'}];
var delay = 100;
var nextAddress = 0;

function theNext() {
  if (nextAddress < services.length) {
    setTimeout('getDetails("' + services[nextAddress].place_id + '", theNext)', delay);
    nextAddress++;
  } else {

  }
}


function getDetails(address, next) {
  alert('ok');
}


theNext();
```

Errror:

> VM687:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: getDetails is not defined

The function is defined and I'm not sure whats causing the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/qmnaykqw/

Comment: Tested a same scenario in my console, it is working fine.

Comment: Wow!! I'm not sure who is downvoting answers so fast!

Comment: What Quentin has answered + you need to place `nextAddress++;` also in the timed function, now the counter is increased immediately, and will be `1` at the time the timed function is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass a string to `setTimeout` it gets evaluated in the global scope. Since `getDetails` is defined in another function (on your JSFiddle link at least) which is called `onload`, it is out of scope when the string is evaluated.

You need to pass a function to `setTimeout` instead. That will create a closure and preserve the scope.

```
function delayed_function() {
    getDetails(services[nextAddress].place_id, theNext);
}

setTimeout(delayed_function, delay);
```

Comment: Can you look at the script here: http://acleach.me.uk/gmaps/v3/plotaddresses.htm It looks like that guy made it work :/

Comment: @user1012181 — Unlike your JSFiddle version, that code doesn't wrap the code in another function which gets assigned as a load event handler.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. Can you explain with that bit of code? :/

Comment: @user1012181 — What don't you understand? The answer has a paragraph explaining what the problem is, a paragraph explaining the solution, and then a drop in replacement for the broken code.

Comment: Yes I understand what you have given in the answer section. But if you check the link I provided, that guy is passing the function as a string.

Comment: @user1012181 — And on that page `getDetails` is a global. On your JSFiddle it is scoped to the onload event handler function.

Comment: Even in this case, the nextAddress++; is happening soon.

Comment: @user1012181 — Then have its initial value be one lower.